# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, microsoft-office

Erro ao executar as seguintes linhas de código:

```
Result res = new Result();

foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Equals("Microsoft Excel (32 bit)")
        || clsProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper().Equals("EXCEL")
        || clsProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper().Equals("EXCEL.EXE"))
    {
        clsProcess.Kill();
        break;
    }
}
res.BytesPDF = null;
res.Message = "";
res.Status = false;
res.OutputPath = "";
try
{
    var tmpFile = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempExcelLocation"];

    var tmpFileStream = File.OpenWrite(tmpFile);
    tmpFileStream.Write(ExcelContent, 0, ExcelContent.Length);

    tmpFileStream.Close();

    tmpFileStream.Dispose();

    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Equals("Microsoft Excel (32 bit)")
            || clsProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper().Equals("EXCEL")
            || clsProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper().Equals("EXCEL.EXE"))
        {
            clsProcess.Kill();
            break;
        }
    }

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook doc = excel.Workbooks.Open(tmpFile);
```

Dá o seguinte erro
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC quando se executa a última linha.

O Office que estou a usar é o Office 2019.

podem ajudar?

Comment: vê se este link te pode ajudar: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6f2884f0-5dd2-471c-874c-a7203862effa/how-to-solve-the-error-quotexception-from-hresult-0x800a03ecquot?forum=exceldev

Comment: @Carla é um arquivo `xls` ou `xlsx`?

Comment: Quantas linhas existem na planilha que está tentando abrir? É .`xls` ou `.xlsx`?

Comment: xlsx. 356 linhas.